# $f$ such that $\|Df - \text{Id}\|$ is close to zero, yet $f$ is not bijective

Tags: multivariable-calculus

A problem from my differential geometry class:

*Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is a $C^1$ mapping, and for every $x\in \mathbb{R}^2$*

$$\| Df(x) - \text{Id} \| < 10^{-10}.$$

*Prove or disprove: $f$ must be a bijection.*

My intuition tells me that there should be a counterexample. $f$ linear will not work, because either it is an isomorphism, or it has range of dimension $\leq 1$, in which case $\|Df - \text{Id} \| = \|f - \text{Id}\|$ will be too big.

One idea I had is a function which on the complex plane would be expressed as $z\mapsto z^{\alpha}$, where $\alpha - 1$ is positive and very close to zero. This would certainly not be a bijection, but should not move anything on the unit circle too much. The derivative of such a function would be the matrix representing the complex number $\alpha (a+bi)^{\alpha -1}$. It seems like this matrix would be sort of tricky to come up with. $\alpha(a+bi)^{\alpha -1} :=\alpha e^{(\alpha-1) \log{(a+bi)}}$, and how can I simplify this?

I know this function is not complex-differentiable at zero, but perhaps it is differentiable when viewed from $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$?

Any hints or ideas? No need to feed me the answer. Thanks

Comment: Eric, that function you're trying to define isn't well-defined on $\Bbb C$. And, moreover, the derivative is not close to the identity globally.

Comment: @TedShifrin Shoot, really? Why is it not $re^{i\theta} \mapsto r^{\alpha}e^{i\alpha \theta}$?

Comment: Try $\theta=0$ and $2\pi$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Darn, we need a branch cut for that one, I think.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Let $g(x) = f(x) - x$.  If $f(x) = f(y)$, $x - y = \int \ldots$

Comment: The Mean Value Inequality might be better than a nebulous integral. But I was hoping people would let Eric figure it out rather than giving it away.

Comment: Well, that's why I made it nebulous.

Comment: I've heard of cloud computing, but cloud integrals are new to me.

Comment: Hmmm...I'm not seeing it completely. $Dg = Df - \text{Id}$, so we can bound $\|g(y) - g(x)\| = \|x-y\|$ above by using mean value inequality, but what good is bounding $\|x-y\|$ above? Also, I'm not seeing what $x-y$ has to do with any integral. (Here $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^2$, right?)

Comment: If $0 \le d \le c d$ where $c < 1$, what can you conclude about $d$?

Answer (score 1):

This is basically the same as Robert's solution but with solving $y=f(x)$ as the motivation.

Consider looking for solutions to $y=f(x)$ by reformulating as a fixed-point problem. In this case we could try $y-x+x-f(x) = 0$, which can be written as $y+x-f(x) = x$. So, we look for fixed points of $\phi_y(x) = y+x-f(x)$.

We see that $\|\phi_y(x_1)-\phi_y(x_2) \| \le \sup_\xi \|I-\frac{\partial f(\xi)}{\partial x} \| \|x_1-x_2\|$, and so $\phi_y$ is a contraction.

Comment: Where you write $\frac{\partial f (\xi)}{\partial x}$, do you mean $Df(\xi)$? (Just different notation, I think.) So this argument would seem to imply that if $\|Df - \text{Id}\| \leq \eta <1$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$, then $f$ must be a bijection. This is not what I expected!

Comment: Yes, $Df(\xi) = \frac{\partial f(\xi) }{\partial x}$. And yes, $\eta<1$ is sufficient.

Comment: Can the $\sup$ in your comment be taken over $\xi$ on the line between $x_1$ and $x_2$, or must it be over a larger set?

Comment: If you want to show that $f$ is bijective for all $x$, then the $\sup$ is over all $x$.